# Spring Data JPA fails to invoke JtaTransactionManager

Tags: spring, transactions, openjpa, spring-data-jpa, atomikos

I am using Spring Data JPA (SDJ) and during my integration tests, I've come across a weird situation - I've probably misconfigured something, but I fail to see what that might be.

In a nutshell - it would seem that SDJ simply fails to invoke an implementation of Spring's `PlatformTransactionManager` once there is *any* kind of method declared on repository interface (i.e., the one that extends `JpaRepository<T, ID>`). 
I've drilled down this behaviour to a pretty banal reason - in this situation, `JtaTransactionManager`'s setter simply does not invoke, but I couldn't figure out the reason.

Should interface lack any method declaration - everything works as is it should: the `JtaTransactionManager` setter invokes normally and transactions initiate, but I  **really** dislike writing unneeded custom Repositories just to get around a possible misconfiguration/bug (and I have confirmed implementing a custom repository indeed circumvents mentioned behaviour).

I would appreciate any info you may give me as I am running out of ideas here.

This is my relevant stack:

- JDK 1.5
- Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE
- Spring Data JPA 1.1 GA (issue confirmed on version 1.0.3)
- Atomikos 3.7.0
- OpenJPA 2.0.1
- DB2 9.7

This rudimentary interface will execute normally:

```
package org.test
public interface TestDAO extends JpaRepository<Test, Integer> {}
```

The following repository interface will cause the exception below:

```
package org.test
public interface TestDAO extends JpaRepository<Test, Integer> {
//public static final String TEST = "SELECT t FROM Test t WHERE t.code=:code"; 

//@Query(TEST)
List<Test> findByCode(String code);}
```

Provoked exception (the exception is thrown during Spring application context bootstrap, in "configuration-time"):

```
08:23:40.296 | DEBUG | [o.s.d.r.c.AbstractRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser:110] | Triggering auto repository detection
08:23:40.997 | DEBUG | [o.s.d.r.c.AbstractRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser:233] | Registering repository: testDAO - Interface: org.test.TestDAO - Factory: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean, - Custom implementation: null
.....
08:23:41.309 | DEBUG | [o.s.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy:113]         | Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository@6d886d88]
08:23:41.338 | DEBUG | [o.s.d.j.r.query.SimpleJpaQuery:122]               | Looking up query for method findByCode
08:23:41.342 | DEBUG | [o.s.d.j.repository.query.NamedQuery:108]          | Looking up named query Test.findByCode
08:23:43.451 | TRACE | [openjpa.jdbc.SQL:83]                              | <t 16515324, conn 2070969200> executing prepstmnt 694298978 SELECT SEQSCHEMA AS SEQUENCE_SCHEMA, SEQNAME AS SEQUENCE_NAME FROM SYSCAT.SEQUENCES
08:23:43.551 | TRACE | [openjpa.jdbc.SQL:83]                              | <t 16515324, conn 2070969200> [99 ms] spent
08:24:07.248 | INFO  | [o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:433]         | Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6d966d96: defining beans [....]; root of factory hierarchy
08:24:07.253 | INFO  | [o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:441] | Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'xxx'
08:24:07.307 | ERROR | [o.s.test.context.TestContextManager:324]          | Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [....] to prepare test instance [org.test.SomeIntegrationTest@64026402]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.syncWithManagedTransaction(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:720) ~[openjpa-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
Wrapped by: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.syncWithManagedTransaction(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:752) ~[openjpa-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.initialize(BrokerImpl.java:371) ~[openjpa-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.initialize(BrokerImpl.java:315) ~[openjpa-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:231) ~[openjpa-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:215) ~[openjpa-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156) ~[openjpa-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:227) ~[openjpa-persistence-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:154) ~[openjpa-persistence-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.5.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79) ~[na:1.5.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.5.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618) ~[na:1.5.0]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:517) ~[spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy24.createEntityManager(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:234) ~[spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy31.createNamedQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery.hasNamedQuery(NamedQuery.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery.<init>(NamedQuery.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery.lookupFrom(NamedQuery.java:111) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:160) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:68) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:280) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:148) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:125) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:41) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```

When you delve into the code that bombs (OpenJPA `AbstractBrokerFactory` class), it follows that OpenJPA expects the given transaction manager (as defined in OpenJPA properties map below), but Spring doesn't provide it, since setter on `JtaTransactionManager` class is not invoked at all (I've verified this behaviour while debugging).

Contrary to that, if interface without any methods is invoked, the setter is called normally and provides transaction manager to OpenJPA.

Here's my configuration - one thing that you may notice and could potentially be relevant: I am not using `persistence.xml` file at all.

**Datasource**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="${dataSource.uniqueName}" />     
    <property name="xaDataSourceClassName" value="${dataSource.className}" />
    <property name="poolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="250" />
    <property name="borrowConnectionTimeout" value="5000" />
    <property name="xaProperties">
        <props>
        //snipped for brevity....
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Transaction manager**

```
<!-- Construct Atomikos UserTransactionManager, needed to configure Spring -->
<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="3600"/>
</bean>

<!-- Configure the Spring framework to use JTA transactions from Atomikos -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
</bean>
```

**Entity manager**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${entityManagerFactory.persistenceUnitName}"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.test.model" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties" ref="openjpaProperties" />
</bean>
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaDialect"></bean> 
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter"></bean>
```

**OpenJPA properties**

```
<util:map id="openjpaProperties">
        <!-- Specifies whether JPA is using Managed (global) transactions or Local transactions -->
        <entry key="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed" />
        <entry key="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed" />
        <entry key="openjpa.ConnectionFactory2" value-ref="dataSourceNonXA" />
        <!-- Specifies transaction manager to be used -->
        <entry key="openjpa.ManagedRuntime" value="invocation(TransactionManagerMethod=com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionManagerImp.getTransactionManager)" />
</util:map>
```

**JPA repository scanner**

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="hr.apisit.b28.intrastat.business.storage.codelists.internal.dao" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include the test code. It is not very clear from the question what exactly is the problem you are facing? How did you conclude that the JTATransactionManager is not used?

Comment: I have updated my question and added a few clarifications. I think the test is irrelevant, as it is not during the test that this exception is thrown, but rather, during test context construction, so during Spring bootstrap. Even so, the test is trivial (essentially just calls the given method declared in Repository interface) and I'd rather not add any more noise to an otherwise extraordinary long post.

Comment: You can reproduce the same issue even if you don't have the Query annotated method - write a simple test that tries to use one of the existing methods. The issue is while creating a new EntityManager - when the Query annotated method is present spring data apis are trying to create one during configuration.

Comment: I agree, you'll notice I have also commented-out the @Query annotation from repository method declaration and the issue still persists. Currently, the only way I've been able to circumvent this is to define a custom repository implementation. Interestingly, in this case, even though TestDAO doesn't extend TestDAOCustom (and its TestDAOImpl), transaction manager is set and bootstrap continues, but what bothers me is that I can't see SDJ is trying to construct query by method name, but is just using the custom repository implementation (even though my repository is not extending it!).

Comment: My last comment might not be right - it could be a bug in spring data. I think the entity manager creation will fail if the transaction is not in place - which is what could be happening at startup. It shouldn't be trying to create an EntityManager during startup - maybe there is some configuration to do this as a part of the first request instead of at startup.

Comment: I don't quite see the arguments here and you probably have to get into more details. The exception is caused by the Spring Data infrastructure trying to lookup a named query. According to the spec the `EntityManager` must throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if it doesn't exist, nothing else. No query execution happens here. I don't see why the EMF needs to lookup something related to a transaction to do so. Same for the case of `@Query`. We call `em.createQuery(…)` which does not need any TX activity at all. I'd file a bug against OpenJPA wondering why EM instance creation needs TX activity.

Comment: Thank you for your hints, I'll try to find some time to study this behaviour more properly. Do you see anything fishy with the posted configuration? I basically fail to understand why would something related to query lookup engine have the need for transactions and I am still not familiar with Spring Data JPA APIs - could you provide some classes in Spring Data infrastructure that could serve as entrypoints for further bugchasing?

Comment: Nothing fishy to see. You're actually experiencing a `NullPointerException` in an OpenJpa class. Open a bug in there tracker and feel free to post it here to follow up.

Comment: I've just filed a bug report on OpenJPA JIRA (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2234) so let's see what they have to say about this.

Comment: @OliverGierke -- Can you tell me why com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionManagerImp.getTransactionManager is returning null? That is the problem here.

Comment: You'll probably better ask that in the Atomikos bug tracker ;)

Comment: @Rick - I would just like to remind that it's due to Spring's JtaTransactionManager setter is not invoked, hence no tx-mgr is injected and I suspect that's why Atomikos' method is returning null. I couldn't root out the cause as to _why_ is that setter not invoked - only that it is not invoked when using method query lookup facilities of Spring Data JPA. That being said, we're in the process of migrating our DAO layer to Hibernate and I have to say we currently don't experience the error/behaviour in that ORM.

Comment: @Quantum -- I don't think it is OpenJPA's responsibility to configure / setup the TransactionManager. Via configuration, you told OpenJPA to call a certain method to get the TM... and it isn't there. I vote this  is a problem with configuring OpenJPA / Spring / Atomikos. If you're punting on trying to solve this issue, can I have you close your JIRA?

Comment: @Rick - well, since I opened up the issue on recommendation from Oliver, I think it's appropriate he also has a say in this. I must say that I tend to agree with you (which is why I opened the ticket on Spring Data JPA in the first place), however, I would like to hear Oliver's point of view before I decide on closing the OpenJPA ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to init the atomikos transaction manager at startup. So, the only thing needed here is to add this:

`<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" init-method="init" destroy-method="close" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="forceShutdown" value="true" />
    </bean>`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<jpa:repositories base-         package="hr.apisit.b28.intrastat.business.storage.codelists.internal.dao" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
            transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" depends-on="transactionManager"/>
```